# Necesito ayuda Bloques-PL/SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola me podrian ayudar resolve este ejercicio por favor , no entiendo que estructura de control podría usar , muy amable por su tiempo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola. Si bien las preguntas sobre ejercicios son bien recibidas, debes demostrar que hiciste hasta ahora y donde tienes problemas concretamente. En tu pregunta, a que te refieres con estructura de control? Saludos!

Comment: Hola , a mi parecer estoy haciendo esto select employee_id,last_name,count(*) as cantidad from employees where email='SKING'
group by employee_id,last_name;                                                       Pero en el ejercicio dice que si ingresas la cadena ''Var" , te mostrara esa imagen en la cual me sale nula , y estructura de control me refiero a while , for, loop .

Comment: por favor, toda la informacion que sea de la pregunta agregala usando el boton [edit] dentro de la misma

Comment: @QuevedoKevin, lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: while, for o un loop en general es una estrutura de iteracion. de control es un if o un case. Igual, para empezar tu SP debe recibir un parametro.. es por donde deberias empezar..

Comment: claro  avance hasta aqui : set serveroutput on;
declare
correo EMPLOYEES.EMAIL%type;
begin

select employee_id,last_name from
employees where email=&correo;

end;